# Extract Year / Month from a TimeStamp variable in JPQL

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

In a JSF+JPA application, a timestamp property named as 'createdAt' needs to be searched by the year and month. I have used Extract(Year, createdAt), but it gives an error.

The persistence provider is EclipseLink 2.6 (which is the current default in Netbeans). The database is MySQL.

This is a simplified query

```
select c from Client c where EXTRACT(YEAR,c.createdAt)=:ey and  EXTRACT(MONTH,c.createdAt)=:eq
```

The error is

```
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select count(distinct c)    from ClientEncounterComponentItem i join i.itemClient c  where i.retired=:f  and i.item=:v1  and i.integerNumberValue>:d1 and EXTRACT(YEAR,c.createdAt)=:ey and  EXTRACT(MONTH,c.createdAt)=:eq  and i.itemClient.person.province=:area    ]. 
[154, 166] The right expression is not a valid expression.
[167, 263] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Comment: Simplify your query - is the problem with Extract or some other clause?

Comment: Simplified the query

Comment: Why not use "select c from Client c where EXTRACT( YEAR, c.createdAt ) = :ey" and show the new exception message and stack trace?  As per ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions ) you might also try " EXTRACT( YEAR FROM c.createdAt ) = :ey"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions shows the correct format for the query should be:

```
select c from Client c where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c.createdAt)=:ey and  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.createdAt)=:eq
```

EclipseLink unit tests validate this format works when using the Hermes parser on databases that support it.

Comment: What is Hermes parser? Does MySQL support that? Searched google, but failed.

Comment: Hermes is a parser EclipseLink uses for JPQL processing to help it generate its expressions and then SQL.